# How to use java Java configuration class in spring integration xml file related to apache kafka?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

we are using xml file to implement apache kafka using spring-integration. for now producer and consumer factories are called using @bean in xml file. but I want to read configurations from java class and use that class in the xml file. How do I do that for producer and consumer?

current version for producer:

```
<int:chain input-channel="kafka-output-channel">
        <int:object-to-json-transformer/>
        <int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                            kafka-template="template"
                                            topic="${topic.name}" />
    </int:chain>

<bean id="pf" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="${broker.list}" />
                <entry key="key.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"/>
                <entry key="value.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

<!-- Kafka Template -->
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="pf"/>
</bean>
```

But I want to create class like below and use beans below in the xml file,

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, appConfig.getBrokersList());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }
}
```

same thing I want to do for consumer part!

could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is changed here. The XML and Java & Annotation configurations contributes to the same `ApplicationContext` and bean declared in one place can be references in the other, and wise versa. So, to use that `kafkaTemplate` bean in the XML, you just need to use exactly this name instead of that `template` and remove those bean definitions in the XML.

Only the problem that annotation configuration has to be primary: use an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. Although I see that you use Spring Boot, so everything is OK. Your XML config has to be used on some `@Configuration` class as a `@ImportResource`. On the other hand if you have already enough experience with annotations configuration, there might not be a reason to stick with XML config even for Spring Integration. Consider to investigate Java DSL which smoothly replaces whatever you can have in XML: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl

Please, also pay attention that there is an auto-configuration for Apache Kafka in Spring Boot. So you might not need to configure your template and produce/consumer factories: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka